# Check for called methods with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric 2.2 and want to improve my tests a bit. Currently I want to check if a method of mine calls `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()`. The source to test contains lines like:

```
  public void setFragmentManager(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
  }

  public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    :
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

This should make it easy to mock such a `FragmentTransaction`. I guess I know how to do this with Mockito, but Robolectric claims that no further mocking framework is required:

> **No Mocking Frameworks Required**
>
> An alternate approach to Robolectric is to use mock frameworks such as
>   Mockito or Android Mock to mock out the Android SDK. While this is a
>   valid approach, it often yields tests that are essentially reverse
>   implementations of the application code.
>
> Robolectric allows a test style that is closer to black box testing,
>   making the tests more effective for refactoring and allowing the tests
>   to focus on the behavior of the application instead of the
>   implementation of Android. You can still use a mocking framework along
>   with Robolectric if you like.

Now I'm not sure if I can't find how to solve my problem with Robolectric or I should go ahead and use Mockito. I tried to make it work with `org.fest.reflect.*` stuff, but I failed.

What I'd like to know is:

1. How do I do this with Robolectric?
2. Or should I use Mockito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just quickly checked `Robolectric` shadow classes and `FragmentManager` API. And I haven't any method that helps with pending transactions.

So I would suggest you to use `Mockito` until there are such methods. For sure `Robolectric` usage is preferred over `Mockito` because of better code design (no unnecessary injections like in your case `FragmentManager`)